# SqlConnection doesn't get closed after using statement

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have problem with SqlConnection in ADO.Net. I expect that after end of using{}, the connection will be closed automatically. Why isn't it?

```
public void Connect()
{
    using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("got connection");
        Console.WriteLine("retrieving a scalar value");
            
        Console.WriteLine(cnn.State);
        int allRows;

        string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [AdventureWorks2019].[Person].[ContactType]";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(cnn.State);
            allRows = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(cnn.State);
    }
}
```

I get output:

```
got connection
retrieving a scalar value
Closed
Open
Open
```

I expected:

```
got connection
retrieving a scalar value
Closed
Open
Closed
```

I already use `POOLING=FALSE;` in connection string, but didn't change anything

Comment: You haven't demonstrated what you think you have. The final `Console.WriteLine(cnn.State);` happens before the `using` block disposes of the connection.

Comment: @madreflection, thanks, i edit it, but i expected that `using` dispose connection immediately after last row: `allRows = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` when ending curly brackets

Comment: Why would you assume that? That using block disposes the `SqlCommand` instance. Why would it also dispose of the `SqlConnection` instance which is scoped to its own `using` block in your code? What about the use case where you want to run multiple serial commands using the same open connection and wrap that in a transaction? If you were to assume `SqlCommand.Dispose()` also disposes the `SqlConnection` that would no longer be possible.

Comment: Side point: do *not* turn off pooling unless you really know what you are doing. It is meant to be there and improves performance

Comment: Also side note: the `ExecuteNonQuery()` really isn't suitable to *retrieve* data - it's designed to execute `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE` statements that *don't return* any data sets. To fetch a scalar value - use `ExecuteScalar()` instead